# save listView content to a file

Tags: c#, listviewitem

I'm trying to save the contents of my listView.
But I'm having some issues with it. In my text file it will look like this:

```
ListViewItem: {1234};ListViewSubItem: {daily};ListViewSubItem: {Backup};ListViewSubItem: {Every 2 days at: 23:0};ListViewSubItem: {};ListViewSubItem: {}
```

But I don't like that it adds "ListViewItem:" and "ListViewSubItem:" etc with my data.. I just want those strings inside {}.

And here is my code:

```
        FileStream file = new FileStream(dataFolder + "\\BukkitGUI\\schedule.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file);

        foreach (ListViewItem listItem in listView1.Items)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(listItem + ";" + listItem.SubItems[1] + ";" + listItem.SubItems[2] + ";" + listItem.SubItems[3] + ";" + listItem.SubItems[4] + ";" + listItem.SubItems[5]);
        }

        sw.Close();
        file.Close();
```

Any help on this?

EDIT: Image of my listView:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that I get it. The code snippet that you provided, more specifically the `foreach` loop - is this what cause the unwanted result in the `.txt` file or this is your attempt to fix it?

Comment: @Leron It's what causing it..

Comment: @Leron updated my question with a image of my listView.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem listItem in listView1.Items)
{
    sw.WriteLine(listItem + ";" + listItem.SubItems[1] + ";" + listItem.SubItems[2] + ";" + listItem.SubItems[3] + ";" + listItem.SubItems[4] + ";" + listItem.SubItems[5]);
}
```

This is doing the following:

```
foreach (ListViewItem listItem in listView1.Items)
{
    string listItemString = listItem.ToString();
    // etc.
}
```

What do you think the value of `listItem.ToString()` will be?

The default implementation of `object.ToString()` simply outputs the name of the type. The implementation for `ListViewItem` and `ListViewSubItem` apparently output the name of the type, plus the content of the item or subitem.

If you want something different output, then you need to do it yourself. Output `listItem.Text` and `listItem.SubItems[n].Text` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's too long to post it as comment so I'll write an answer. I hope at least it will give you a good direction on one way to deal with it. In general you need some way to manipulate string. Many options comes to mind, but in your case I think that using `regex` or regular expressions is the best option since they are powerful, you have a clear criteria about what should go inside the `.txt` file and what not, and you work with relatively small amount of data so even though the regular expressions are considered slower than other options, in your case I think this won't be a problem.

Here is what I've tried - just created a static method (some sort of helper method) that will clean the string for you so that you get only the info you need. The method itself is :

```
    public static string ParseListView(string ListViewText)
    {
        var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("{.*?}");
        var match = regex.Match(ListViewText);

        return match.ToString().TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}');
    }
```

Pretty simple method. There's a lot of things that you can adjust if needed to work better for your case. For example I'm using `regex.Match()` which returns only the first match, but maybe you'll find `regex.Matches()` more suitable for you. There are also a lot of other options when you work with regular expressions in `C#` so be sure to check them out.

Then in you `foreach` loop you just:

```
foreach (ListViewItem listItem in listView1.Items)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(ParseListView(listItem) + ";" + ParseListView(listItem.SubItems[1]) + ";" + ParseListView(listItem.SubItems[2]) + ";" + ParseListView(listItem.SubItems[3]) + ";" + ParseListView(listItem.SubItems[4]) + ";" + ParseListView(listItem.SubItems[5]));
        }
```

Of course this looks pretty ugly so the logic inside the `foreach` loop most probably can be improved but I think this will get you going.

Answer (score -1):

Q: If your input data is in JSON format, perhaps your best bet is to get a JSON parser?

For example:

- [Parsing REST Services JSON Responses (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx): illustrates System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

Otherwise, if it's just a "funny format", look at the .Net TextFieldParser:

- [Parsing Text Files with the TextFieldParser Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x710fk43.aspx)

Comment: It's nothing to do with JSON i think. It is a listView with multiple columns. That each column have some strings. That I want in my text file..

Comment: So look at TextFieldParser.  Here's another [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/07/07/whats-a-nice-class-like-textfieldparser-doing-in-a-namespace.aspx) with some examples.